# help - stripes appeared in artificial grass lawn!

Tags: lawn, grass, lawn-repair

I just left a rented house with artificial grass lawn. The landlord's gardener came a week after we left and claims that we damaged the lawn and made stripes in it! of course we didn't, and we never saw these stripes before... what could be the cause? is it something the gardener did? Is it natural erosion that happens over time?

[image: stripes_in_lawn1]
[image: stripes_in_lawn2]

Comment: This is the gardener pure and simple if you've not been involved with the yard.  Looks like a double wheeled appliance...one with 4 wheels.  Spreading fertilizer yet it is coming out of the spreader through the wheel wells. Where do you live and what type of grass is this again?  Artificial grass?  Astro turf?  If this is St. Augustine that gardener is mowing too short.

Comment: It looks to me like the landlord's (blind?) gardener mowed half the artificial turf, then realized that was a bad move, and is trying to blame you for it!

Comment: Agree with alephzero. Go pick up a handful of green plastic clippings before you head to small claims court. Even a bagger-mower will leave some behind.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger, alephzero, thanks! I'll try to get some evidence.  stormy - we live in Israel, the climate is very hot (and so is the grass once the sun hits it...), but I have no idea which type is it.

Comment: I was about to post the same as alephzero - the grass most definitely looks mowed. As well as gathering clippings, you could measure the height of the non-mowed part vs. the "mowed" part - sure looks like a definite difference in photo 2. If you find clippings and can prove a height difference, I'd also be prepared for the "gardener" to blame YOU for mowing the grass. Maybe contact the landlord without the gardener's knowledge and  show him/her the evidence before the gardener hears about your findings.